# Is MANOVA appropriate?

Tags: r, manova

So I've been reading various online tutorials and I've not come across and example which is similar to what I'm trying to do. I've thought up this example because I was struggling to explain with words alone. It's really basic but hopefully illustrates the concept:

```
movie_eg=data.frame(score_children=c(1.1,2.5,3.9,1.5,4.3),
                    score_adults=c(12.5,13.1,18.1,13.1,18.8),
                    brad_hrs=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.6),
                    angelina_hrs=c(0.2,0.6,0.8,0.9,0.1),
                    cgi_budget=c(0.9,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.8),
                    seat_cost=c(0.1,0.3,0.6,0.1,0.9))
rownames(movie_eg)=c("shrek","bourne","lockstock","scream","sharknado")
```

So in reality I have over 400 "movies" each with 2 continuous outcomes ("scores") and 4 predictive measurements ("brad","ang","budget","seats") which are also continuous. The two "scores" are moderately correlated across "movies".

I'd like to see if there is a strong connection between any/all of the predictive values and the two outcomes - so here, what (if anything) influences both "scores"?

Therefore, I believe that the "dependent variables" are the two outcomes and the "independent variables" are the four predictions.

So I would do:
`summary.aov(manova(cbind(brad_hrs,angelina_hrs,cgi_budget,seat_cost)~cbind(score_children,score_adults),data=movie_eg))`

and then see all P values are greater than 0.05, so nothing had a strong effect on score? But that seat_cost was the best predictor (although still not significant)?

```
Response seat_cost :
                                    Df  Sum Sq  Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
cbind(score_children, score_adults)  2 0.45417 0.227085  17.583 0.05381 .
Residuals                            2 0.02583 0.012915
```

(Probably worth mentioning in reality the "scores" are measures of drug response and the predictions are measures of different cellular functions, so really nothing to do with movies!)

Comment: Looks like you've got it backwards... the DVs go to the left of the "~" in your equation, and the predictors to the right. It should look more something like: manova(cbind(score_children,score_adults) ~ brad_hrs + angelina_hrs + cgi_budget + seat_cost, data=movie_eg)